# How can I route myApp İnside of App even if my <a> tag has target:"_blank" in Capacitor

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

How can I route myApp İnside of App  even if my  tag has target:"_blank" in Capacitor Angular
ı try so many ways bu ı cant sucseed

I try that think with deep linking but thats not what ı want. I want directly route in my app

Comment: There are examples in the Angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: This is possible, just keep in mind that when you open an Angular app in a new page, it has to load the whole application again. This defeats the whole point of SPAs (single page application)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes ı know Angular route but that was different. there is a big project write with a angular and ı convert that capacitor ionic app so I dont want to change absoluteUrls and  open all pages in my app